# dismissing a stack of view controllers

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

According to the documentation `dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:` will allow you to dismiss an *entire stack* of view controllers by merely dismissing the controller on the bottom of the stack. When I try this, only the top controller is being dismissed.

For example, consider the figure below where controller A and B have both been presented modally. If I dismiss A then both A and B *should* be dismissed, but *only* B is being dismissed!

[image]

Below is the action that is trigged when the user click on B's button. The root view controller dismisses A (its presented controller), but only B is dismissed!!

```
- (IBAction)dissmissAandB:(id)sender {
    AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    ViewController *rootViewController = 
         (ViewController *) appDelegate.window.rootViewController;
    [rootViewController.controllerA dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{}];Below
}
```

The root view controller's `controllerA` property is set when the first segue is prepared (i.e., when A is presented). Any ideas why this is not working as advertised?

Comment: Hva you checked unwind segues? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12561735/what-are-unwind-segues-for-and-how-to-use-them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I discovered the correct call is

```
[rootViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{}];
```

instead of

```
[rootViewController.controllerA dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{}];
```

The receiver of the method is the controller that presented the bottom controller *not* the bottom controller itself.